# NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION in Mockit test class in Springboot

Tags: java, mockito

I am getting NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION on running this test class that I am writing for my springboot application. I am not sure what the problem is, I tried using initMocks too.

**BookControllerTest.java**

```
package com.example.junitrestapiapplication;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BookControllerTest {
    AutoCloseable openMocks;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
     ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
     ObjectWriter objectWriter= objectMapper.writer();

     @Mock
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

     @InjectMocks
    private BookController bookController;

     Book RECORD_1 = new Book(1L, "Atomic Habits" , "How to build better habits"  , 5);
     Book RECORD_2= new Book(2l, "Thinking Fast and Slow", "How to create good mental models about thinking", 4);
     Book RECORD_3= new Book(3L, "Grokking Algorithms","learn algorithms the fun way",5);

     @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
         MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
         this.mockMvc= MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(bookController).build();

     }

     @Test
    public void getAllRecords_success() throws Exception{
         List<Book> records= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(RECORD_1, RECORD_2, RECORD_3));
         Mockito.when(bookRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(records);
         mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
                 get("/book").
                 contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).
                 andExpect(status().isOk()).
                 andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$", hasSize(3))).
                 andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$[2].name", is("Grokking Algorithms")));

     }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-rest-api-application</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>junit-rest-api-application</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
            <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
            <version>10.16.1.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**BookRepository.java**

```
package com.example.junitrestapiapplication;


import org.springframework.data.domain.Example;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Sort;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.FluentQuery;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.function.Function;

@Repository
public class BookRepository implements JpaRepository<Book, Long> {

    @Override
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> findAll(Sort sort) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Page<Book> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> findAllById(Iterable<Long> longs) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long count() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteById(Long aLong) {

    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Book entity) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllById(Iterable<? extends Long> longs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll(Iterable<? extends Book> entities) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAll() {

    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book> S save(S entity) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book> List<S> saveAll(Iterable<S> entities) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Book> findById(Long aLong) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean existsById(Long aLong) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void flush() {

    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book> S saveAndFlush(S entity) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book> List<S> saveAllAndFlush(Iterable<S> entities) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllInBatch(Iterable<Book> entities) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllByIdInBatch(Iterable<Long> longs) {

    }

    @Override
    public void deleteAllInBatch() {

    }

    @Override
    public Book getOne(Long aLong) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Book getById(Long aLong) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Book getReferenceById(Long aLong) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book> Optional<S> findOne(Example<S> example) {
        return Optional.empty();
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book> List<S> findAll(Example<S> example) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book> List<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Sort sort) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book> Page<S> findAll(Example<S> example, Pageable pageable) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book> long count(Example<S> example) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book> boolean exists(Example<S> example) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <S extends Book, R> R findBy(Example<S> example, Function<FluentQuery.FetchableFluentQuery<S>, R> queryFunction) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**BookController.java**

```
package com.example.junitrestapiapplication;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/book")
public class BookController {
    @Autowired
    BookRepository bookRepository;
    @GetMapping
    public List<Book> getAllBookRecords()
    {
        return bookRepository.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "{bookId}")
    public Book getBookbyID(@PathVariable(value = "bookId") Long bookId)
    {
        return bookRepository.findById(bookId).get();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Book createBookRecord(@RequestBody   Book bookRecord)
    {
        return bookRepository.save(bookRecord);
    }
    @PutMapping
    public Book updateBookRecord(@RequestBody   Book bookRecord ) throws  Exception {
        if(bookRecord==null || bookRecord.getBookId()==null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Book Record or ID must not be null");
        }
        Optional<Book> optionalBook=bookRepository.findById(bookRecord.getBookId());
        if(!optionalBook.isPresent())throw new Exception("Book with ID: "+bookRecord.getBookId()+" does not exist");

        Book existingBookRecord=optionalBook.get();
        existingBookRecord.setName(bookRecord.getName());
        existingBookRecord.setSummary(bookRecord.getSummary());
        existingBookRecord.setRating(bookRecord.getRating());

        return bookRepository.save(existingBookRecord);
    }
}
```

**Book.java**

```
package com.example.junitrestapiapplication;

import com.sun.istack.NotNull;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="book_record")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class Book {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long bookId;
    @NonNull
    private String name;
    @NonNull
    private String summary;

    private int rating;
}
```

I am receiving MockMvc: null on debugging. I have tried changing initialization of Mock.

Comment: I think the issue is with your imports. Which JUnit versions are you trying to use? I see a mix-and-match between JUnit4 and JUnit5.

Comment: I am using JUnit 5

Comment: `@Before` is annotation that belongs to JUnit4. Please look at my answer below. You should use `@BeforeEach`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between `@BeforeEach` and `@Before` is the version of JUnit they belong to. `@BeforeEach` is used in JUnit 5 (JUnit Jupiter) and offers more flexibility and improved features than `@Before` in JUnit 4.

If you're using JUnit 5, using @BeforeEach for setup operations is recommended. However, if you're using JUnit 4, you should use @Before.

Try replacing your imports and use correct method:

Replace the following imports

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
```

With

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
```

Class

```
package com.example.junitrestapiapplication;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.ResultMatcher;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static net.bytebuddy.matcher.ElementMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasSize;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.status;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class BookControllerTest {
    AutoCloseable openMocks;
    private MockMvc mockMvc;
     ObjectMapper objectMapper= new ObjectMapper();
     ObjectWriter objectWriter= objectMapper.writer();

     @Mock
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

     @InjectMocks
    private BookController bookController;

     Book RECORD_1 = new Book(1L, "Atomic Habits" , "How to build better habits"  , 5);
     Book RECORD_2= new Book(2l, "Thinking Fast and Slow", "How to create good mental models about thinking", 4);
     Book RECORD_3= new Book(3L, "Grokking Algorithms","learn algorithms the fun way",5);

     @BeforeEach
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
         MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
         this.mockMvc= MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(bookController).build();

     }

     @Test
    public void getAllRecords_success() throws Exception{
         List<Book> records= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(RECORD_1, RECORD_2, RECORD_3));
         Mockito.when(bookRepository.findAll()).thenReturn(records);
         mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.
                 get("/book").
                 contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).
                 andExpect(status().isOk()).
                 andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$", hasSize(3))).
                 andExpect((ResultMatcher) jsonPath("$[2].name", is("Grokking Algorithms")));

     }
}
```